# in electron-forge, "npm run make" give me the error "not find git in environment"

Tags: git, dependencies, electron-forge

I start a progect with NodeJs and Electron
.
In the terminal of VSCode
when I esecute one of the 2 following commands:
"npx electron-forge import"
or
"npm run make"
it gime me the followin error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlsOX.png)
how can I fix it?
.
P.S. if instead I execute these commands in git bash
are performed correctly

I update npm, NodeJS
I install the last version of git

.
.
I reinstall Git and now it work in vscode, with this setting (during the Git installation)

[image]

Comment: If you run "git -v" in CMD does it work?

Comment: No, it don't work

Comment: Please add the error message as **pure text** in the question, not an image.

Comment: So it seems like you have installed "git" incorrectly. Maybe tell how did you install it

Comment: the cause of my problem was an error during the installation of Git, during the configuration of Git I selected "Use Git from Git Bash only" but this cause that git do not work in vscode - - - - - - Instead when I reinstall Git and select "Use Git from command line and from 3rd-party command software" then Git work also in vscode